# Удаление файла из директории php+mysql

Tags: php, sql

Прочитав статьи попытался сделать удаление картинки из директории:

```
$getfile = mysql_query("SELECT I.filename FROM timages I LEFT JOIN tholidaysimages AS TH ON TH.imageid=I.id WHERE hotelid=".$hotelid);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($getfile)) {      
                $file = $row->pic; 
                unlink("../../static/uploads/holidays/$file");
```

На входе функции имею только $hotelid
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: У вас в запросе поле называется `filename`, почему вы ниже к нему обращаетесь по имени `pic` ? И `LEFT` в `JOIN` абсолютно не уместен, вам же не требуется получать записи из картинок вне зависимости есть для них записи во второй таблице или нет

Comment: А поле hotelid - оно в какой таблице-то?

Comment: Не дало результата, hotelid в таблице tholidaysimages
в SQL данный запрос корректен, выгружает имена файлов с расширением полностью. Возможно проблема в том что файл функций находится в admin/modules, а директория в static/uploads/holidays
т.е. нужно подняться на уровень выше, а потом зайти в static/.......

Comment: Если знаете абс. пути, то почему пользуете относительные? и как у пользователя, от которого работает пхп, с правами в файловой системе? Кстати, а какие симптомы заставили спрашивать _Что я делаю не так?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akina и Mike спасибо за помощь.
Итоговый работающий вариант, кому полезен будет:

```
$getfile = mysql_query("SELECT I.filename FROM timages I LEFT JOIN tholidaysimages AS TH ON TH.imageid=I.id WHERE hotelid=".$hotelid);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getfile)) {      
                $file = $row["filename"];
                unlink("../static/uploads/holidays/".$file); 
            } 
            mysql_query("UPDATE tholidays set status=0 where id=".$hotelid);
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM timages WHERE timages.id IN
                       ( SELECT tholidaysimages.imageid FROM tholidaysimages  
                         WHERE tholidaysimages.hotelid = $hotelid)");
```